# wifidog authentication server request http://serverdomain/install/3 got an error

Tags: linux, apache, wifi, router, openwrt

i want to use the wifidog's authentication for auth user access network , and configuration on a apache2 server, and use the official site http://www.authpuppy.org/doc/Getting_Started to configured it , but when i request the step 3 i got a url: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/install/3` and Not Found

The requested URL /install/3 was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

i really need a help , thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this. I had forgotten to enable rewrite on my apache install.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this, I was having the same problem. just for future reference if anyone founds this issue do the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

Add the following, please mind to change the path /var/www/...:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/authpuppy>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then restart:

```
 sudo  /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```